# React Material UI Textfield value={}

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I would like to ask help why Textfield in material ui won't receive a value. I am using material ui together with React and Typescript. It won't render the values necessary for that specific textfield however would give a [object Object] value.

Here's my source code:

```
const [formInfo, setFormInfo] = useState<CustomFormInformationProps[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/customforminfo")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((formInfo) => setFormInfo(formInfo.formsinfodata));
  }, []);

  console.log("Form Info", formInfo);

  return (
    <div>
      {formInfo.map((customform) => (
        <TextField sx={{ m: 1, width: 1 / 2 }} value={customform} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

For the formInfo, here are the values:

```
{
    "ne_type": "ne12344",
    "alarm_severity": "major",
    "description": "ok",
    "multiline": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    "select": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "Oliver Hansen",
            "value": "Oliver Hansen"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "Oliver",
            "value": "Oliver"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "label": "Hansen",
            "value": "Hansen"
        }
    ],
    "radio": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "Foo",
            "value": "foo"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "Bar",
            "value": "bar"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "label": "Test",
            "value": "test"
        }
    ],
    "checkbox": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "Japan",
            "value": "JAP"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "Canada",
            "value": "CAN"
        }
    ],
    "date": "06-27-2022",
    "time": "06-30-2022 18:03:00",
    "datetime": "06-30-2022 10:30:00",
    "link": "Link Component"
}
```

These are the values of customForm too,

```
{
    "ne_type": "ne12344",
    "alarm_severity": "major",
    "description": "ok",
    "multiline": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    "select": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "Oliver Hansen",
            "value": "Oliver Hansen"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "Oliver",
            "value": "Oliver"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "label": "Hansen",
            "value": "Hansen"
        }
    ],
    "radio": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "Foo",
            "value": "foo"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "Bar",
            "value": "bar"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "label": "Test",
            "value": "test"
        }
    ],
    "checkbox": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "Japan",
            "value": "JAP"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "label": "Canada",
            "value": "CAN"
        }
    ],
    "date": "06-27-2022",
    "time": "06-30-2022 18:03:00",
    "datetime": "06-30-2022 10:30:00",
    "link": "Link Component"
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the entire `formInfo` object from the fetch?

Comment: Actually yes, if you can show us what's inside of `formsinfodata` prop of `formInfo` from your fetch. Let's see what's in there

Comment: They both have the same value since the formsinfodata and the formInfo. @KitangaNday

Comment: So `formInfo` isn't an array?